# Google Analytics 4 Data API can't get values of multiple metrics query

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I trying to get values of `totalUsers`, `activeUsers`, `newUsers`

My runReport code:

```
$response = $client->runReport([
 'property' => "properties/$site->google_property_id",
   'dateRanges' => [
     new DateRange([
       'start_date' => '30daysAgo',
       'end_date' => 'today',
      ]),
     ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(['name' => 'date',])],
    'metrics' => [
      new Metric(['name' => 'totalUsers']),
      new Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers']),
      new Metric(['name' => 'newUsers']),

    ],
    'orderBys' => [
      new OrderBy([
       'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
       'dimension_name' => 'date', // your dimension here
      ]),
     'desc' => true,
     ]),
    ],
 ]);
$params['analytics'] = $response->getRows();
```

Problem: i can't get values of with `$row->getMetricValues()` and `$row->getMetricValues()[1]` but not working

````
@foreach ($analytics as $row)
 @foreach ($row->getMetricValues() as $dimensionValue)
   '{{$dimensionValue->getValue()}}',
 @endforeach
@endforeach```
````

Comment: try `dd($analytics)` and show result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something very similar querying how many `activeUsers` there are grouped by country in a given timeframe:

```
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => '************',
    'dateRanges' => [new DateRange(['start_date' => '2022-07-01', 'end_date' => '2022-08-01'])],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers'])],
    "dimensions" => [new Dimension(['name' => 'country'])]
]);

$total_active_users = 0;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $country) {
    $country_name = $country->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue();
    $active_users = $country->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();

    $total_active_users += $active_users;

    echo "The country '$country_name' had $active_users in this time frame.\n";   
}

echo "In total, we got $total_active_users active users globally in this time frame.\n";
```

.. i think the fix you're looking for is `$country->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()`, I hope this helps.